# Android: files saved inside getFilesDir() disappear after application restart

Tags: android, android-studio, save, storage, missing-data

I want to save a file to app-specific storage, like shown in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-store-stream):

```java
String filename = "myfile.txt";
String fileContents = "Hello world!";
try (FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)) {
    fos.write(fileContents.toByteArray());
}
```

Unfortunately, every time I restart the application all data are lost.

How to prevent data from being deleted?

Please note I am not interested in using SharedPreferences/External Storage/Database. Android Studio 3.5.3.

Comment: It turned out that, instead of using _try-with-resources_ statement, I actually used just pure _try_ and therefore stream remained open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the file once you are done using it. Otherwise it is not stored to the disk, but only to the memory.
That's why when you "shut down" the app, and start over, it's not there anymore.

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    try  {
        fos.write(fileContents.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
       try{
       if (fos!=null){
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();
        }
       } catch( Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```